# using the 'class' keyword as/in a method argument in c#

Tags: c#, class, keyword

I'm not sure where I saw this, and I'm certainly not getting the syntax past the compiler.
Is it possible to use the 'class' C# keyword as part of a method parameter signature?

foo(string x, class y)
{
}

Anyone else see something like this?
thanks,
-gene

Comment: It really depends on how you want to call it; that could be `object`, `Type`, or generics - possibly a few others too.

Answer (score 8):

Should you be using object maybe?  It looks like you are trying to specify a parameter that can have any type, in which case you should use object, since everything derives from it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use it as in your example, but if you would want to use the word "class" as a parameter name, that is doable by prefixing it with @:

```
foo(string @class) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the word class in in a generic method definition:

```
foo<T>(T object) where T:class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object if you want to be able to pass y as anything:

```
foo(string x, class y) { }
```

use generics if you want to state y has to be an object of a class - not a struct or an internace for example.

```
foo<MyType>(string x, MyType y) where MyType : class { }
```