# Where keyword class can be used in c#?

Tags: c#

I know 2 places where the class keyword is used in c#.

1. In class declaration
2. In generic constrains (class GenericClass where T : class)

But is there anything I've missed? It's importan to me, becouse I'm writing a program wich counts classes in a file. Can find no info in msdn or C# specification.

### Edit

```
#if class
partial class C<T> where T : class
{
    // class!
    int @class = 123;
    string c = "class";
}
partial class C<T> where T : class {}
#else
partial class D {}
partial class D {}
partial class D {}
#endif
```

This is accumulation of several answers.

Comment: "class" is also usable as variable names (@class) as well as in string which I'm sure you already know.

Comment: You would get a more reliable count by using reflection against the assemblies, but this might be what you are looking for if you are analysing the source.

Comment: You could use the visual studio extension APIs to count classes.  It's probably better at it than you are.

Comment: What kind of "file"? A .cs source file? A compiled DLL?

Comment: @benPearce This is good solution, that I would use in real life, but this program will be tested on realy big files (1gb), so reflection will not handle compiled assembly

Comment: If he is counting a single file, reflection/APIs won't help him much. His only garaunteed way of counting them in a single file is to build a lightweight parser.

Comment: May be you have some partial classes and this causes to counting them two times.

Comment: @er-v Why is it you think just because the file is >=1GB that reflection or codeDOM won't handle it?

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield actually you right, the size of sourse file does not means anything, but number of types does. When I call GetTypes for assembly with 1 000 000 classes I get StackOverflowException.

Comment: Have you considered [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just counting occurences of "class" does not tell you how many classes are in a file:

```
#if FOO
partial class C 
{
    // class!
    int @class = 123;
    string c = "class";
}
partial class C {}
#else
partial class D {}
partial class D {}
partial class D {}
#endif
```

The string "class" appears eight times in there, but the file only defines a single class.

Comment: @EricLippert Well, the question is not about how to solve the problem. Partial classes is not a big problem. I can use stack and build names depends on namespaces, classes and nested classes. Is there any other places where keyword class can be used in C#?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use something like ANTLR ( http://www.antlr.org/ ) and use for example something similar to this SO post [Partial grammar for counting class count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914073/partial-grammar-for-counting-class-count) . I think it is safer than trying to write your own parser.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible to use `class` as an identifier by preceding it with an "at" sign.

```
int @class = 1;
```

I'm not saying it's *advisable* to write that, but you might want to consider it if you're trying to count classes.

**Related**

- [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

Comment: finally i know how to give my variables the name `@var` and `@param`!

Comment: I know it, but keyword class is not used here. Just the _word_ class is used )

Comment: Note that this is not only for variables but for any identifier.

Comment: @er-v: What else are you expecting? The two that you have listed are the _only_ two real uses of the keyword.  Look in the spec... look in the documentation... it's all there.

Comment: @JeffMercado Actually there is no place in documentation where it's clearly stated, that this is only real uses. I'm expecting that this the is only, but I can't be shure.

Comment: @er-v: Yes, it is. Read the grammar that is *fully* specified in the, wouldn't you know, specification.

Comment: @pivotnig: Not sure about `param` off the top of my head, but you can already give your variables the name `var` (but please don't).  You can even have a class named var, but future users of your code will hate you.  Code like `var var = new var {q = "3"};` is legal if you have a `var` class.

Comment: @Brian thanks, you're right, `param` and `var` work as any other identifier without the @... TIL: something useless :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can have `class` defined as a compilation conditional symbol, e.g.

```
#if class
#else
#endif
```

...and it compiles if you define it in the project properties / build.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any other usage but remember that you can use keywords as identifiers if they are prefixed with @

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the keyword class in a generic method definition:

```
foo<T>(T object) where T:class
```

Use object, if you want to be able to pass `y` as anything:

```
foo(string x, class y) { }
```

Comment: foo(string x, class y) { } - does not compile, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps some compilers don't allow this.

Comment: I could find the same thing also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293850/using-the-class-keyword-as-in-a-method-argument-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @Lion, or perhaps all compilers don't allow this.